# Imagick script not even loading on WAMP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I successfully installed Imagick on WAMP and everything looks fine. However when I run this PHP Imagick script, nothing happens but this default error page comes up.

```
try
{
    $image = 'image.jpg';

    $im = new Imagick($image);

    echo 'Imagick';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

[image]

However, I realized that this error only happens when I pass the argument when creating the Imagick object.

If I create Imagick object without the arguments, it works fine.

```
$im = new Imagick();
```

So, that's the problem. I can't find any errors since this doesn't give any error message.

This is my phpinfo() page and see how imagick configuration

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: make sure that the image is in the same folder as the script. 
please try to specify the full path to the image and see if it works?

Comment: yes, check on the image path. Also enable PHP's Error Reporting, and Display Error.

Comment: @PepeBolo Thanks! It worked! Giving full path like `D:\Localdisk\MyFolder\filename.jpg` fixed the problem. However, I'm wondering why that `try catch` block is not working. If image cannot be found, it should pass the exception. Instead it's just not loading.

Comment: @RyanHarne Thanks, but I tried enabling error reporting. But no luck. It doesn't even go to the script. So, no errors showing. :-(

Comment: i see, those must notice error level, better use file_exists() to check it then

Comment: Yeah, that should do the trick!